# VBA - current cell value duplicating in other cells with same (user defined) function

Tags: vba, excel

new here, so apologies if I miss some etiquette.

I wrote a VBA function in Excel. It seems to work correctly for the current cell, but it is duplicating its value in all cells with that function.

That is - Many cells in Column Q have this formula =ScoreQ5(). If I am in cell Q2 and hit F2 to update the value, it will update Q3, Q4, etc., and make those equal to the value of Q2.  So Q2 will be correct, but the others may not be.

I thought maybe I shouldn't be using ActiveCell, but I can't find anything online that suggests it should do this.  Any thoughts?

Thank you

Here is the code of the function

```
Function ScoreQ5()
Application.Volatile
Dim LDoF200 As Integer
Dim LDoF225 As Integer
Dim HDoF204 As Integer
Dim HDoF205 As Integer
Dim LDoF50P As Integer
Dim LDoF51P As Integer
Dim HDoF50P As Integer
Dim HDoF51P As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim current As Long
Dim question As Long
Dim LDoF As Integer
Dim HDoF As Integer

current = 0
LDoF200 = 0
LDoF225 = 0
HDoF204 = 0
HDoF205 = 0
LDoF50P = 0
LDoF51P = 0
HDoF50P = 0
HDoF51P = 0
question = 0
LDoF = 0
HDoF = 0
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Cells(i, 2) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -15) Then
    current = current + 1
        If StrComp(Cells(i, 11), "5 - RedChemical_Threshold") = 0 Then
        question = question + 1
            If Cells(i, 24) = 200 Then
                If StrComp(Cells(i, 9), "LDoF") = 0 Then
                LDoF = LDoF + 1

                    If Cells(i, 23) = 200 Then
                    LDoF200 = 1
                    ElseIf Cells(i, 23) = 225 Then
                    LDoF225 = 1
                    End If

                    If Cells(i, 25) = 50 Then
                    LDoF50P = 1
                    ElseIf Cells(i, 25) = 51 Then
                    LDoF51P = 1
                    End If
                Else
                HDoF = HDoF + 1

                    If Cells(i, 23) = 204 Then
                    HDoF204 = 1
                    ElseIf Cells(i, 23) = 205 Then
                    HDoF205 = 1
                    End If

                    If Cells(i, 25) = 50 Then
                    HDoF50P = 1
                    ElseIf Cells(i, 25) = 51 Then
                    HDoF51P = 1
                    End If
                End If
            Else
            End If
        Else

        End If
    Else
    End If
Next i

If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8) = "LDoF" Then
    If LDoF200 + LDoF225 = 2 Then
        ScoreQ5 = 2
    ElseIf LDoF50P + LDoF51P = 2 Then
        ScoreQ5 = 1
    Else
        ScoreQ5 = 0
    End If
Else
   If HDoF204 + HDoF205 = 2 Then
        ScoreQ5 = 2
    ElseIf HDoF50P + HDoF51P = 2 Then
        ScoreQ5 = 1
    Else
        ScoreQ5 = 0
    End If
End If

End Function
```

Comment: A worksheet function like this should be taking a range argument(s) and not relying on `ActiveCell` at all. This is becasue when the formula evaluates (and it is a volatile formula), only one cell is "active", it does not refer to *each* cell in which the formula has been entered.

Comment: Also, cells using this UDF on *non-active sheets* will update using inputs from whichever sheet is active...

Comment: Thanks for these comments. I feel dumb, but I can't figure out how to use range to refer to the cell that the formula calling the function is in.  That is, if the function is in cell Q2, what VBA refers to cell Q2 without specifying it?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a custom user defined function (aka UDF) for the worksheet. If you are unsure of how to accomplish certain facets of the custom function, look at how native worksheet functions handle the same problems.

Your function works (to some extent) in column Q because you have hard coded cell range references with the [Range.Offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx). Imagine what would happen if you could only use the [SUM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) or [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) functions in column Q. They work anywhere because you tell them where to find data with parameters. Your UDF should work the same way.

The [ActiveSheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [ActiveCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) properties do not simply 'turn off' once you have a result for your UDF. They change every time you make another selection within the workbook. This means that your UDF will recalculate according to the new [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) and this is exasperated by your use of the [Application.Volatile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195441.aspx) method. Further, selecting any cell from columns A:O will result in an error since there can be no `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -15)` to reference.

Pass your parameters into the UDF as cell and range references just as you would with any native worksheet function. If you absolutely need to reference the worksheet that the UDf is on, the [Range.Parent property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980(v=office.11).aspx) of any cell you reference can provide this. In a pinch, this can be coupled with the [Application.Caller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193687.aspx) property of the UDF itself.

Your narrative describes the use of your original UDF in column Q and I will base my interpretation of the offset columns on that.

```
Function ScoreQ5(rngB As Range, rngI As Range, rngK As Range, _
                 rngW As Range, rngX As Range, rngY As Range, _
                 Optional strK As String = "5 - RedChemical_Threshold", _
                 Optional intX As Long = 200, _
                 Optional strI As String = "LDoF", _
                 Optional intWa As Long = 200, _
                 Optional intWb As Long = 225, _
                 Optional intWc As Long = 204, _
                 Optional intWd As Long = 205, _
                 Optional intYa As Long = 50, _
                 Optional intYb As Long = 51)

    Application.Volatile

    Dim LDoF200 As Integer
    Dim LDoF225 As Integer
    Dim HDoF204 As Integer
    Dim HDoF205 As Integer
    Dim LDoF50P As Integer
    Dim LDoF51P As Integer
    Dim HDoF50P As Integer
    Dim HDoF51P As Integer
    Dim current As Long
    Dim question As Long
    Dim LDoF As Integer
    Dim HDoF As Integer
    Dim i As Long

    current = 0
    LDoF200 = 0
    LDoF225 = 0
    HDoF204 = 0
    HDoF205 = 0
    LDoF50P = 0
    LDoF51P = 0
    HDoF50P = 0
    HDoF51P = 0
    question = 0
    LDoF = 0
    HDoF = 0

    With Application.Caller.Parent
        'cut the (possible) full column ranges down to size
        Set rngB = Intersect(rngB, rngB.Parent.UsedRange)
        Set rngI = Intersect(rngI, rngI.Parent.UsedRange)
        Set rngK = Intersect(rngK, rngK.Parent.UsedRange)
        Set rngW = Intersect(rngW, rngW.Parent.UsedRange)
        Set rngX = Intersect(rngX, rngX.Parent.UsedRange)
        Set rngY = Intersect(rngY, rngY.Parent.UsedRange)

        For i = 1 To rngB.Rows.Count
            If rngB.Cells(i) = rngB.Cells(Application.Caller.Row) Then  'B
                current = current + 1
                If StrComp(rngK.Cells(i), strK) = 0 Then  'K
                    question = question + 1
                    If rngX.Cells(i) = intX Then   'X
                        If StrComp(rngI.Cells(i), strI) = 0 Then  'I
                            LDoF = LDoF + 1

                            If rngW.Cells(i) = intWa Then  'W
                                LDoF200 = 1
                            ElseIf rngW.Cells(i) = intWb Then
                                LDoF225 = 1
                            End If

                            If rngY.Cells(i) = intYa Then  'Y
                                LDoF50P = 1
                            ElseIf rngY.Cells(i) = intYb Then
                                LDoF51P = 1
                            End If

                        Else
                            HDoF = HDoF + 1

                            If rngW.Cells(i) = intWc Then  'W
                                HDoF204 = 1
                            ElseIf rngW.Cells(i) = intWd Then
                                HDoF205 = 1
                            End If

                            If rngY.Cells(i) = intYa Then  'Y
                                HDoF50P = 1
                            ElseIf rngY.Cells(i) = intYb Then
                                HDoF51P = 1
                            End If
                        End If
                    Else
                    End If
                Else
                End If
            Else
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If StrComp(rngI.Cells(i), strI) = 0 Then  'I
        If LDoF200 + LDoF225 = 2 Then
            ScoreQ5 = 2
        ElseIf LDoF50P + LDoF51P = 2 Then
            ScoreQ5 = 1
        Else
            ScoreQ5 = 0
        End If
    Else
       If HDoF204 + HDoF205 = 2 Then
            ScoreQ5 = 2
        ElseIf HDoF50P + HDoF51P = 2 Then
            ScoreQ5 = 1
        Else
            ScoreQ5 = 0
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

> <sup>Syntax:</sup>
>      =ScoreQ5(B:B, I:I, K:K, W:W, X:X, Y:Y)

The above modifications should serve to get you started. I do not have sample data nor expected results to fully test on. I'm not entirely sure why you are cycling through all of the rows if you finish off by comparing the collected values to **2**. Is there no chance that after going through all of the rows that something like `LDoF50P + LDoF51P` could never be greater than **2**? Perhaps, these might have been handled better by boolean vars rather than integer type vars. I have passed a number of your comparison constants in as optional parameters. They can be used as is or you can modify the parameters by putting in additional values.

---

<sub>I have been trying to proselytize the use of cutting full column references down to the extents of the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) in UDFs. This allows you to quickly use full column references when implementing your UDF on the worksheet while not suffering calculation lag from processing a large number of blank cells. tbh, I think more native worksheet functions could use some of the same pre-processing on their own cell range parameters.</sub>

Comment: thanks for the amazingly thorough response!  I appreciate the guidance on good practices.  I had thought along similar lines, but knew that I had limited scope for this function. I would never use this function in a different column than the current one, and I thought this would be easier for another user. Of course someone might temporarily insert a column and break it...  Regarding the max value of 2.  Basically, the goal of the function is to take an ID from column B and check whether it meets the criteria of havings x and y, and if not, a and b (for all rows with that value in column B).

Comment: Thanks for your kind comments. Did I get close to a working function?

Comment: The function ran without error, but it did not get the correct answer.  What should have come as a 2 score, instead came as a 0.  I think it is probably close, but I was able to make mine work by using the Application.Caller.Row example from your code.  I am going to keep yours as a model for when I develop another similar item.